# merge the contents of XML file

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, notepad++

Currently i have two XML files

one.xml                       //First File

```
    <LayoutEntry     name="b1t2mci"           value="$cfg_opt/one"           type=""/>
    <LayoutEntry     name="b1t1ul"            value="$cfg_opt/two"            type=""/>
    <LayoutEntry     name="b1t1fcv"           value="$BattCfgOpt/three"           type=""/>
```

two.xml               // Second File

```
    <cfgOpt>
        <one value="0" />
        <two value="9" />
        <three value="8" />
    </cfgOpt>
```

i need to replace the value attribute in first XML  with one found in second XML file .

I.e   value="$cfg_opt/one"  needs to replaced as  value="0" . As the value is zero in the second XML file .

Since there 1000's of rows in the file  , is there any way to automate it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't have any idea to automate it.But Yes you can merge xml files.You could do this with the DOM parser and XPath- refer code below to merge your file. Do necessary changes in code below to achieve structure of your XML.

```
public class MergeXmlDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
// proper error/exception handling omitted for brevity
File file1 = new File("merge1.xml");
File file2 = new File("merge2.xml");
Document doc = merge("/run/host/results", file1, file2);
print(doc);
```

}

```
 private static Document merge(String expression,
  File... files) throws Exception {
XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression compiledExpression = xpath
    .compile(expression);
return merge(compiledExpression, files);
```

}

```
  private static Document merge(XPathExpression expression,
  File... files) throws Exception {
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
    .newInstance();
docBuilderFactory
    .setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory
    .newDocumentBuilder();
Document base = docBuilder.parse(files[0]);

Node results = (Node) expression.evaluate(base,
    XPathConstants.NODE);
if (results == null) {
  throw new IOException(files[0]
      + ": expression does not evaluate to node");
}

for (int i = 1; i < files.length; i++) {
  Document merge = docBuilder.parse(files[i]);
  Node nextResults = (Node) expression.evaluate(merge,
      XPathConstants.NODE);
  while (nextResults.hasChildNodes()) {
    Node kid = nextResults.getFirstChild();
    nextResults.removeChild(kid);
    kid = base.importNode(kid, true);
    results.appendChild(kid);
  }
}

return base;
```

}

```
  private static void print(Document doc) throws Exception {
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
    .newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory
    .newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
Result result = new StreamResult(System.out);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

}

}

Comment: i want the value should be set to the content of another file